# Nodejs middleware for specific requests

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to have the middleware for these routes:

```
POST /tickets
PUT /tickets/:id
DELETE /tickets/:id
etc...
```

but currently my middleware executes on every HTTP request made on /tickets and so on:

```
app.use('/tickets', function(req, res, next) {

    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {      
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });    
            } else {
                req.decoded = decoded;    
                next();
            }
    });
 } else {

      return res.status(403).send({ 
          success: false, 
          message: 'No token provided.' 
    });

    }
});
```

How could I use this on specific requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express has post/get/delete methods for routing. More at [documentation](https://expressjs.com/ru/4x/api.html#app.post.method)

Your should write middleware function and reuse that at routing.

Example:

```
function JWTCheckMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
      } else {
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({
      success: false,
      message: 'No token provided.'
    });
  }
});

app.post('/tickets', JWTCheckMiddleware, function createTicket(req, res) {...});
app.put('/tickets/:id', JWTCheckMiddleware, function updateTicket(req, res) {...});
app.delete('/tickets/:id', JWTCheckMiddleware, function removeTicket(req, res) {...});
```

Comment: To add to this explanation, `.use` is for applying middleware to run anytime a route / sub route of that path is triggered. So using the get/post/put/delete handlers themselves will mean it only triggers the middleware on those specific endpoints, even if there's a more specific path (/tickets vs /tickets:id).

So only use `.use` if you want it to be global (to the specific path).